# Basement bathroom construction

Tags: bathroom

So the mysterious three drains in the basement slab ARE drains.  Have poured gallons and gallons of water down each and it drains away.

So next step is putting this whole thing together.  With the drains already in, should same me massive $$$.  Where do I start though?  I know I need to run water in there and electrical.  Will have friend do that.  Need to finish the walls, put in a subfloor over the slab.

I mean is there a certain way to put this whole thing together?  Common sense right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the water "goes away" doesn't mean it's going into a septic-rated drain (septic system or town sewer).

In all probability the floor drains are running to a dry well somewhere, as they are intended solely to handle leakage or local spills.

You have to connect your planned bathroom waste lines to a legal output.  Do not attempt this on your own unless you're a licensed plumber; in any case you need a building permit first.

Comment: When I bought the house, the original owner stated that when built they had drains installed for a second basement.  Just never got to putting the bathroom together